# UPnP Platinum framework how to turn on logging?

Tags: logging, frameworks, log4net, upnp

To me need turn on log, I know that for logging upnp_framework using log4net, maybe somebody already did it and can help? I'll appreciate it.

Comment: What are you trying to ask?  Do you want to know what logging facilities PlatinumUpnp offers?  Or do you also want to push any logging through log4net?

Comment: No, I want how to turn on logging at PlatinumUpnp